# Solve for the variable $P$ in $C - R = \left(\frac{R}{P}\right) \times 200$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just need to get $P$ on one side of the equation. Thank you

$$C - R =  \left(\frac{R}{P}\right) \times 200$$

Answered by Math Learner:

$$P = \left(\frac{200R}{C - R}\right) $$

---

Now I need to solve for R and I am not sure if this is correct...

From the original equation I added $R$ to both sides, then multiplied by $P$, then divided by $200$. Finally I added the 2 $R$'s, then divided both sides by $2$.

$$R = \left(\frac{CP}{400}\right) $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? It is expected that you show your work up until where you got stuck. View [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for further info

Comment: Your question is not clear. As far as I have understood:
$C-R=\frac RP \times 200  \implies P=\frac R{C-R} \times 200$

Comment: @Math-Learner How did you get there?

Comment: Look I have added another line.  $C-R=\frac RP \times 200  \implies P \left(C-R\right) =R\times 200 \implies P=\frac R{C-R} \times 200$

Comment: Divide both sides by $200$, take the reciprocal of both sides, then multiply both sides by $R$. That's another way to do it.

Comment: @PrimeMover This gives me  P = (200 / C - R) / R  Thats not the same as Math-Learners answer

Comment: @emptyPigeon It shouldn't do. Divide both sides by $200$ gives you $\dfrac {C - R} {200} = \dfrac R P$. Take reciprocals of both sides to get $\dfrac {200} {C - R} = \dfrac P R$. Multiply both sides by $R$ and you get $\dfrac {200 R} {C - R} = P$ which is the same as what ML got.

Comment: @PrimeMover Thank you, I divided R my bad

Comment: can you edit your post to include what have you tried in solvign for $R$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I did

Comment: how did you get that answer?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh From the original equation I added R to both sides, then multiplied by p, then divided by 200. Finally I added the 2 R's, then divided both sides by 2

Comment: Can you basically explain what do we have to find in this questtion? I am really confused by the language here

Comment: @JitendraSingh Find R, sorry the original question "Find P" was answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me follow your attempt:

> From the original equation I added $R$ to both sides, then multiplied by $P$, then divided by $200$. Finally I added the $2$ $R$'s, then divided both sides by $2$.

$$C=R+\left(\frac{R}{P} \right)200$$

You then multiply by $P$:

$$PC=PR+200R$$

I don't see why would I divide by $200$ at this step, also, check your current step, I can't follow your next moves closely. At this step, I would factorize $R$.

$$PC=(P+200)R$$

Finally I would divide by $P+200$.

Comment: Wonderful approach to solve the question / +1